# Custom Shape in ArCore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arcore

I know how to add a sphere or cube in ArCore in Flutter.

But the question is: how can I add a custom shape or object in it?

Is it possible to add import it from Blender, Unity or other 3D applications?

Comment: I've also been searching on how to do this, perhaps replicating and adjusting the existing shapes might work

Answer (score 4):

Right now seems like is not possible to add custom shapes in ARCore. However, using AR Foundation of Unity, you can embed that code in flutter to be used in ARcore and ARKit.

For more information visit [this page](https://connect.unity.com/p/flutter-unity3d-ar-foundation)